# How to create a list of faces from a list of edges in python?

Tags: python, geometry

I'm working with computational geometry and I ran into a problem.
I got to a point where I was able to associate all the vertices of the object to create edges, saving them in a list of pairs:
Ex: `edges = [[p1, p2], [p1, p3], [p2, p3], [p2, p4], [p3, p4]]`[To create something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fykY5.png)

What I would like to do is associate these edges to create faces, and store those faces as lists, like this:
Ex: `faces = [[p1, p2, p3], [p2, p3, p4]]` [To create something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQqhL.png)

In this example I agree that it would be possible to iterate the list of edges and test all possibilities
something like this

```
edges = [[p1, p2], [p1, p3], [p2, p3], [p2, p4], [p3, p4]]
faces = []

for pair1 in edges:
   for pair2 in edges:
      #Some test to see if the edges connect
      faces.append(set(pair1 + pair2))
```

But in my work, I use much longer lists than the one in the example, which would make it impracticable to test one by one. 
Is there any way to associate the pairs so that the edges connect and form faces?

P.S. Not necessarily the faces must be triangular, they can be quadratic or hexahedral.

Comment: The very capable `networkx` package should be able to do this.  https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.planarity.PlanarEmbedding.html

Comment: I'd suspect that finding cycles in a graph would be helpful.